# How to set min-height and max-height equal to window Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I able to set a div height as min-window height but can't set max-height as windowHeight similar way. Here is the code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {   
     function setHeight() {
         windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
         $('.sidebar').css('min-height', windowHeight);   
     };   
     setHeight();
     $(window).resize(function() {
         setHeight();   
     }); 
 });
```

Comment: `$('.sidebar').css('min-height', windowHeight + 'px');` you were missing units.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need javascript nowadays to do that. Pure CSS is sufficient (and just `height` would be enough as well since you want to set `min-height` and `max-height` to the same value):

```
.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

`vh` is a relative unit referring to the height of the viewport. And it even works when resizing the window. Btw, same goes for `vw` which is the width of the viewport.

[More information on the set of relative units](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) and its [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) (as proposed by comments).

Comment: Support link added to answer.

Comment: using `height: 100%` should work here. I don't see why we should use `vh` units.

Comment: Using `height: 100%;` requires you define height for `html` and `body` as well. Viewport units are a blessing.

Comment: +1 Nowadays support for viewport units are good. Finally there's no need to pollute  every child element from the body to the sidebar with `height:100%`

Comment: 100vh may be bigger than window.innerHeight if viewing on safari mobile, for example, due to the overlayed nav buttons

Comment: Well, it shouldn't. And as you say, the nav buttons are _overlayed_, hence the window.innerHeight is still respected properly.

Comment: This is important : just height would be enough as well since you want to set min-height and max-height to the same value

Answer (score 0):

If you want both the min-height and max-height to be the size of the window why dont you just forgo the mins and maxs and just set the height itself?? You are pretty much bang on with your code however I would structure it a little differently. Are you loading the jQuery library?

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    setHeight();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();   
}); 

function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('.sidebar').css('height', windowHeight);   
    console.log(windowHeight);
}
```

This will make the sidebar 100% of the screen height on load and on screen resize.

Alternatively if you are trying to make a page a tablet style web application you can achieve this 100% sidebar with css alone

```
html,body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow:hidden;
}
.sidebar {
   height: 100%;
   /*set overflow-x + y to scrolls if you have a lot of content*/
}
```

this will give you the same effect without any javascript/jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/kdwnk2ax/1/

Comment: I have two images  inside .sidebar one below another which fit full view height.so I want those img height will equally resize when window resize.I use img{max-height:50vh} for those img but is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('.sidebar').css({
    "max-height": windowHeight+"px",
    "min-height": windowHeight+"px"
});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/9kkukk2s/